# Apache Beam SQL JOIN with Side Input

Tags: java, sql, join, apache-beam

Can I SQL JOIN a `PCollection` and a `PCollectionView` (via side input) in Apache Beam SQL?

From [Apache Beam SQL docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/sql/walkthrough/), the way to implement JOIN in the query is to create a `PCollectionTuple` that accepts only PCollections.

```
// Create a PCollectionTuple containing both PCollections.
// TupleTags IDs will be used as table names in the SQL query
PCollectionTuple namesAndFoods = PCollectionTuple
    .of(new TupleTag<>("Apps"), appsRows) // appsRows from the previous example
    .and(new TupleTag<>("Reviews"), reviewsRows);

// Compute the total number of reviews
// and average rating per app
// by joining two PCollections
PCollection<Row> output = namesAndFoods.apply(
    SqlTransform.query(
        "SELECT Apps.appId, COUNT(Reviews.rating), AVG(Reviews.rating) "
            + "FROM Apps INNER JOIN Reviews ON Apps.appId = Reviews.appId "
            + "GROUP BY Apps.appId"));
```

In my pipeline, I have a side input that reads some data from BigQuery table. The side input updates every X hours.

I tried creating PCollectionTuple like this:

```
PCollectionTuple rowsAndSideInput = PCollectionTuple
        .of(new TupleTag<>("PCOLLECTION"), mainCollection)
        .and(new TupleTag<>("MY_SIDE_INPUT"), collectionView.getPCollection());
```

But `.getPCollection()` [say it's an internal function and is not available in all contexts](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/values/PCollectionView.java#L63)

Do you know if it's possible to use Beam SQL JOIN with side input?

Answer (score 1):

`PCollectionView`s are just views of PCollections intended only for use as side inputs. However, this view is being created somewhere, so you should be able to use whatever PCollection was used to create this view rather than trying to use the view itself.

Comment: Hi @robertwb, I've tried joining the "source" PCollection as you suggested, but it doesn't work in my case. What happens is joining two unbounded PCollections (since my "side-input" updates every X hours forever). Beam SQL Join for unbounded is limited - it needs to have the same windows without allowed lateness for both streams. Because my "side input" collection updates once every X hours, I cannot set both collections to the same non global windows without allowed lateness. That's why I asked if it's possible to join with side input data

Comment: You may need to simply implement the Join yourself using a DoFn with side inputs: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#side-inputs

Comment: Yes, this is what we currently do. I tried to refactor that part with Beam SQL but it looks like it doesn't support that use case